# Android: Run function after Activity is created

Tags: android, json, asynchronous, android-activity

Currently, my app starts with a menu. Once a menu item is clicked, it starts a Activity which grabs content from an online API.

The problem I am having is, once the menu item is clicked, the application waits until the http request and response is complete before it displays the activity.

My Question is, How can I have the Activity display instantly with the layout and static View. Then once the activity is loaded, then I start fetching data from an API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why run after when you can run concurrently!!

Use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in your `onCreate()`/`onResume()` method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(...);

    AsyncTask task = new MyTask();
    task.execute(/* optional params */);
}
```

In your implementation of `MyTask`, put your long running code (the data fetched from the http request) into the `doInBackground()` method.  Once the `doInBackground()` method returns, you can update your `View` in `onPostExecute()`.

Also, take a look at [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/05/painless-threading.html), as there is lots of helpful android threading information in there.

Answer (score 2):

You may use either an AsyncTask during the onCreate method to fetch your results and update your activity Asynchronously.  Additionally, I think you may use a separate thread to do the same functionality.  Pretty common use case.  [Here's the relevant Android docs](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).